# Why doesn't model evaluation happen in parallel (Pytorch)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

Given an evaluation of a dataset with a neural network in pytorch like this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = net(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print(f'Accuracy of the network: {100 * correct // total} %')
```

Can someone explain to me why the GPUs are not used to execute the evaluation in parallel? Why does this happen in sequentially, and is there a way to make the model evaluation parallelized?

Comment: What exactly in these lines of code you want to be parallelized?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy The for loop evaluation. So instead of rthe for loop evaluates sequentially, all the evaluation happens together